# What is the best practice to transform the path between proxy and target in apigee?

Tags: apigee

I am making a request /Patient/1 at the proxy endpoint, and I want to transform this into target endpoint /openemr/api. I tried solutions given in `https://community.apigee.com/articles/2793/how-to-geo-locate-calls-to-target-endpoint.html`, but none of these worked for me. Please suggest an optimal way for achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many reroutes you have to implement. So in case of 5+, use a javascript policy, such as:

```
var reqPathsuffix = context.getVariable("proxy.pathsuffix");
var reqVerb = context.getVariable("request.verb");

if ((reqPathsuffix === "/contact") && (reqVerb === "GET"))
{
    endPointURL = "https://yourendpointurl/
}
context.setVariable("target.url",endPointURL);
```

else maybe use a 'AssignMessage' policy.

```
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Assign-Message-1">
  <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
  <AssignVariable>
    <Name>target.url</Name>
    <Value>http://google.nl</Value>
  </AssignVariable>
```

Don't forget to do this on the 'target endpoint preflow request' flow. Else it won't work.